# Button in ForEach Loop triggers multiple times on execution

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a message toast type alerts following [Fancy Toast Messages](https://betterprogramming.pub/swiftui-create-a-fancy-toast-component-in-10-minutes-e6bae6021984)

Then I created a view that loops through a json file of ingredients

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "Spicy Watermelon Mint Agua Fresca",
        "headline": "A refreshing blend of fruity flavor with a blast of spice.",
        "image": "Drink1",
        "equipment": ["Blender", "Strainer"],
        "servingsize": 4,
        "drinkware": "Pitcher",
        "preptime": 10,
        "difficulty": 1.5,
        "rating": 2,
        "category": ["Agua Fresca"],
        "ingredients": [
            "2 cups cold water",
            "2 cups watermelon (rind removed), seeded and chopped",
            "2 tbsp granulated sugar",
            "1 tbsp lime juice",
            ".25 cup mint leaves",
            ".5 jalapeño, roughly chopped",
            "Ice cubes or crushed ice (optional)"
        ],
        "instructions": [
            "Add the ingredients into a blender.",
            "Blend ingredients until mixture is smooth.",
            "Pour mixture through a fine-mesh sieve into a large pitcher, forcing through most of the pulp.",
            "Let chill before serving.",
            "Serve and enjoy!"
        ],
        "shoppinglist": [
            "Watermelon",
            "Granulated Sugar",
            "Lime Juice",
            "Mint Leaves",
            "Jalapeño"
        ]
    }
]

Data model

struct Drinks: Codable, Identifiable, Comparable  {
    static func < (lhs: Drinks, rhs: Drinks) -> Bool {
        lhs.name < rhs.name
    }
    
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var headline: String
    var image: String
    var equipment: [String]
    var servingsize: Int
    var drinkware: String
    var preptime: Int
    var difficulty: Double
    var rating: Int
    var category: [String]
    var ingredients: [String]
    var instructions: [String]
    var shoppinglist: [String]
    
    
}
```

All is displaying and working correctly.

The issue resides in the view that showing this.  I am adding a button that adds the item that is clicked on to a realm database.  That aspect is working on a one to one relationship.

What is displaying or exhibiting undesired behavior is when you click on the plus sign its triggering the message alert for every button that is in the stack.

I am not sure how to separate them out to a 1x1 event with the button so after each click it only fires the event once instead of one time for each button that was added to the view for each item in the ingredients list.

Here is the view

```
import SwiftUI

struct DrinkDetailViewIngredients: View {
  let drinks: Drinks
  @State private var toast: MessageToast? = nil

  var body: some View {
    Spacer()            
    Text("INGREDIENTS")
      .fontWeight(.bold)
      .modifier(TitleModifier())           
    ForEach(drinks.ingredients, id: \.self) { item in              
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {                 
        HStack {
          Text(item)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))
            .frame(minHeight: 50)
            .padding(.leading)
            .foregroundColor(.yellow) 
          Spacer()                        
          Button {
            toast = MessageToast(
              type: .success, 
              title: "Item Added", 
              message: "Item Added to shopping list."
            )
          } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
              .foregroundColor(.yellow)
              .imageScale(.large) 
          }
            .toastView(toast: $toast)
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)                           
        }                        
      }                
    }
  }
}

struct DrinkDetailViewIngredients_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    DrinkDetailViewIngredients(drinks: drinks[0])
  }
}
```

This is what happens when you click the plus sign and the message alert is triggered.

[Message Alert Duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTixN.png)

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, can you please create a [mcve]. Also, please spend the time to format your code to make it easier to read. Lots of blank lines is off-putting for anyone considering trying to read it.

Comment: It should be pretty cut and paste now from my code.  You will have to follow the message link for the toast messages first then you can create the json file and data model to use for the view.

Comment: Adding comments like // Properties immediately before the properties helps no one. We can see it’s a property by the fact that you are defining a property. Just like // BODY immediately before the body is also redundant. And formatting code nicely means you no longer need // END OF … and if you still need them after formatting nicely it’s a sign to break up the code. Not just to throw comments at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to the issue.  I embedded the ForEach Loop in a VStack and then moved the message alert to that VStack versus having the message alert on the button itself.  Here is the final code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DrinkDetailViewIngredients: View {
    //MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    let drinks: Drinks
    @State private var toast: MessageToast? = nil
    
    //MARK: - FUNCTIONS

    //MARK: - BODY

    var body: some View {
        

                
            // Ingredients
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("INGREDIENTS")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .modifier(TitleModifier())
            
        VStack {
            ForEach(drinks.ingredients, id: \.self) { item in
                    
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {

                        
                            HStack {
                                Text(item)
                                    .lineLimit(nil)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    .font(.system(.body, design: .serif))
                                    .frame(minHeight: 50)
                                    .padding(.leading)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.yellow)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                
                                VStack {
                                    Button {
                                        
                                            toast = MessageToast(type: .success, title: "Item Added", message: "Item Added to shopping list.")
                                       
                                    } label: {
                                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color(.yellow))
                                            .imageScale(.large)
                                        
                                    } //:END OF BUTTON
                                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                                    
                                } //:END OF VSTACK
                            } //:END OF HSTACK
                            
                        } //: END OF VSTACK INGREDIENTS

            }//: END OF LOOP INGREIDENTS
        } //: END OF OUTTER VSTACK
        .toastView(toast: $toast)
    } //: END OF BODY
} //: END OF STRUCT

//MARK: - PREVIEW

struct DrinkDetailViewIngredients_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DrinkDetailViewIngredients(drinks: drinks[0])
    }
}
```